# Becoming a web host as an experiment, can anyone explain to me the name server concept?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver, dynamic-dns

I understand everything from nginx virtual hosts to php-fpm user isolation to ssl certs to generating user sub-domains. My question relates to when a user wants to use his own domain he brought from for example Namecheap or Gandi.

**Why does that user need to point the DNS name servers to me, assuming I'm a host? What do I have to do to make it work? Why can't the user just point their A record to my IP?**

Thanks

Comment: For any site to exist, it must be created on a webserver. Otherwise, when a request packet comes in and the requested domain name does not exist, the webserver does not know what to do with the request packet. Often, the webserver will return the first site created. This can be a real site or a catch-all site. You will have to create each site you intend to serve within the webservers configuration. That is a large topic not to be covered here. I suggest you read the documentation for your webserver.